# Mobile slide menu goes under text / Text goes over ul when I press on icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGYhq.jpg)

How can I make the text go under when i press the hamburger(menu) icon.

Comment: Please, show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackOverflow.

Here is an example that may help you:

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Hamburger */

.hamburger1 {
  height: 45px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  z-index: 120;
}

.hamburger1 div {
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#toggle1 {
  display: none;
}

#toggle1:checked+.hamburger1 .top {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 22.5px;
}

#toggle1:checked+.hamburger1 .meat {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#toggle1:checked+.hamburger1 .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

#toggle1:checked~.menu1 {
  height: 340px;
}


/* Menu */

.menu1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #02173F;
  margin: 0;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(4, 0.5fr);
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .4s ease;
  z-index: 120;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menu1 a:first-child {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.menu1 a:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.navlink {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font: 700 20px 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.navlink:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<section class="p-menu1">
  <nav id="navbar" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <input id="toggle1" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="hamburger1" for="toggle1">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="meat"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
    </label>

    <nav class="menu1">
      <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="navlink" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="navlink" href="#">Blog</a>
      <a class="navlink" href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </nav>
</section>
```

I also suggest you to take a look at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp).